# How to use an array property from pom.xml

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I want to use the first developer in the pom as a variable further down in the file.
${developers} returns me an object org.apache.maven.model.Developer@371ff923

${developers[0].email} did not work unfortunately.

```
    <developers>
        <developer>
            <email>abc@google.com</email>
            <organization>yahoo</organization>
        </developer>
    </developers>
```

Comment: Why do you like to do that? What is the purpose of that? Please post the full pom file...

Comment: The developer information will be later sent to another service.

Comment: What kind of service ? During a build? Sounds strange.. Maybe using a plugin for such thing might be the better option.

Comment: I think it's easier to parse the pom.xml and extract this outside of the maven, e.g. with java xml parser. I was able to run `mvn help:evaluate` and print `${project.developers[0].id}`, but no luck with passing the same during resource filtering..